# Unity Constant rotation whilst using Transform

Tags: c#, android, rotation, unity3d-2dtools

This is something i've struggled with all week. I'm working on a 2D project, and what I want is for my enemies to move from the right to the left hand side of the screen (landscape). I'm moving them like this:

```
transform.Translate (new Vector3(1,0,0) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

At the same time, I want them to constantly rotate on a pivot in the middle of the sprite. As an example, imagine they are in space and are sort of floating uncontrollably, they would spin. I've asked this question a couple of times with no response so I guess my explanation isn't really very good. This is what I've tried:

- Animating the objects. This didn't work because changing the Z rotation caused the sprites to spin in a tornado but not from one side of the screen to the other
- This:  `transform.Rotate (0,0,50*Time.deltaTime);` I messed around with the X,Y and Z properties but they pretty much all made a tornado type effect or rotated in 3d so disappeared when at 180 degrees.

I also imported a spritesheet where they are at different points in the "spin" so say at 10,20,30...360 degrees etc. but this wans't smooth at all

I hope this makes sense. I've spend quite a few hours on it now!! I can't get my head around it as I've moved from Xcode where this sort of stuff is 1 line of code. A point in the right direction would be amazing.

Note: if my question makes no sense please ask!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried transform.rotation = Quaternion.lerp() ? I used this myself to rotate an object using an input though you could use it to do a random rotation on the z plane easily enough